# Jquery offset value with respect to browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this

**HTML**

```
    <div id="cbox" class="cbox" name="cbox">
    <div id="box" class="box" name="box"></div>
    </div>
   <span id="posX"></span>
  <span id="posmX"></span>
  <span id="posY"></span>
  <span id="posmY"></span>
  <span id="finalX"></span>
  <span id="finalXm"></span>
  <span id="finalY"></span>
  <span id="finalYm"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
#cbox {
width:1350px;
height: 600px;
border:1px solid #000;
position: relative;
}

#box{
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:25%;
 width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
border:1px solid #000;
background-color: #fff;
padding:10px;
z-index:300;
  }
```

Javascript

```
$('#box').draggable({ containment:'parent', cursor:'pointer',drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var xmPos = offset.left + $('#box').outerWidth(); 
            var yPos = offset.top;
            var ymPos = offset.top + $('#box').outerHeight(); 
            $('#posX').text('xmin: ' + xPos);
             $('#posmX').text('xmax: ' + xmPos);
            $('#posY').text('ymin: ' + yPos);
            $('#posmY').text('ymax: ' + ymPos);
        }, 
          stop: function(){
               var finalOffset = $(this).offset();
            var finalxPos = finalOffset.left;
            var finalxmPos = finalOffset.left + $('#box').width();
            var finalyPos = finalOffset.top;
            var finalymPos = finalOffset.top + $('#box').height();

    $('#finalX').text('Final Xmin: ' + finalxPos);
    $('#finalXm').text('Final Xmax: ' + finalxmPos);
    $('#finalY').text('Final Ymin: ' + finalyPos);
    $('#finalYm').text('Final Ymax: ' + finalymPos);
        }

                      });
```

Basically as the box is being dragged the offset values are being inputted into their respective span fields, everything works perfectly but i noticed the offset values are abit different on ie8+ and opera, is there anyway i can make the offset values the same on across all browsers?
Many Thanks.

Comment: I'm not finding any inconsistencies across browsers http://jsfiddle.net/Xzzhf/

Comment: Hmm i checked on jsfiddle and its consistent but testing it again using my browsers its a bit different, for example, when the box is dragged to the top left corner of the cbox it says xmin 11 and ymin 11 on ie8 but on chrome and moz it says xmin 9 and ymin 9.

Comment: Something else is affecting it's position then.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that margin and padding value actually affect the position and offset value of an element.